# Использование Stream API для поиска значений в JTable

Tags: swing, java-stream

подскажите имеется таблица JTable (swing), можно ли с использованием Stream сформировать список List в который будут помещены номера строк таблицы JTable, которые в 4-м столбце например содержат значение "нет"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, возможно. Будет выглядеть как-то так:

```java
List<Integer> list = IntStream
    .range(0, jTable.getRowCount())
    .filter(rowIndex -> jTable.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).equals("нет"))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Где `colIndex` - номер столбца, который проверяете.